# Max-height property for img in Print Media Not Working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to generate PDF from HTML. However, I want img in PDF to get restricted upto certain height. 
For that I am using below CSS code,

```
@media print  {img { width: 100%; height: auto;  max-height: 1000px;}}
```

When I alter the height of img using this CSS, the changes gets reflected into generated PDF. However, max-height property does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` at the end of `max-height: 1000px;`, for example:

```
@media print  {img { width: 100%; height: auto;  max-height: 1000px !important;}}
```